# Function handle error in matlab

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I want to call function handle `model_jacobian`, but i get  "Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.". When i pick function that leaves both `a` and `d` coefs in jacobian, everything works fine.

```
syms a d x;  
syms_function = a*x+d;                                                    
model_jacobian = matlabFunction(jacobian(syms_function, [a d]), 'vars', {[a d], x});
J = model_jacobian([1 1], [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]');
```

So how to call function handle with arguments despite the fact that they are not used there?

Comment: Replacing the unused argument with [] should work.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this, but you may want to reconsider your `vars` specification.  The documentation says:

> The value of this parameter must be either a cell array of strings or symbolic arrays, or a vector of symbolic variables

You have a cell array of symbolic variables, which does not seem correct.  I would just keep it simple like:

```
'vars',[ a d x])
```